# Bootstrap navbar collapse button not showing on specific device resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with with nabar items on few device resolution. Am debuging in chrome inspector responsive tool. I have to many menu items and when am on `775x550` resolution navbar toggle button is disabled and some menu items goes down out of grid. Looks ugly, on lower resolution all works good

Check example on screenshot.

**This is what i expect:**
[image]

**What i have:** 
[image]

Item goes down, out of gird
[image]

**My debug code:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
                <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

So how to toggle button on on that resolution?

**FIX:**

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-header {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Search ur file css `@media` is check http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: write all styles belonging to class navbar-toggle for your required width in media query including hover, active..

Comment: Not sure what's your question after that Fix you provided. As far as I am concerned you only need to replace (max-width: 1000px) with (min-width:769px). If you want to limit it further you can use (and)

Comment: So does the "Fix" answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The fix your provided will work if you replace

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {}
```

with this

```
@media (min-width:769px) {}
```

See [example](http://www.bootply.com/3Jd6QfW8TJ)